# Use different Git repo for different modules

Tags: android, git, module

In my Android application I've created a new library module. Now I have this structure:

[image]

Right now I have under version control on Bitbucket whole project less datingcorelib. I would like to use a different repo to this library module.

It's possible to use two different repos on the same project?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.You can use, for example, submodules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You're looking for a thing called [submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules).

However, it may be tricky to use such a submodule within a project as it will have its own structure. So you also need to include the right gradle project from that submodule.

Let's say you pushed your library project somewhere. Let it be `git@github.com:Sami/my-library.git`. We also assume that it has the common structure for Android library project, i.e. it has a root `build.gradle` file and a subfolder `datingcorelib` with actual source code. This is what we need to include into the app.

You need to delete `datingcorelib` from your app's project. Then add the library as a submodule:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:Sami/my-library.git libraries/datingcorelib
```

After that open `settings.gradle` file of your app's project and add a new line there:

```
project(':datingcorelib').projectDir = new File("$rootDir/libraries/datingcorelib/datingcorelib")
```

Sync the project. Now you should be able to use the code from another repository.